# GET variable after mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a set of product pages that obey the following htaccess rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([0-9]+)\-(.+)\.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /product/index.php?prod=%1-%2 [L]
```

Which rewrites them to: example.com/123-1234.html.

My problem is that I can no longer pass additional $_GET variables to the page - IE: example.com/123-1234.html?coupon=something123.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The whole point of mod_rewrite is to keep the url and uri intact. You can't access `$_GET['prod']`? The alternative would be to take the url and split it up using explode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your looking for QSA, Query String Append

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([0-9]+)\-(.+)\.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /product/index.php?prod=%1-%2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: @beaudierman: Don't forget to accept this answer if its correct

Answer (score 2):

Add the QSA flag to pass along existing query string params

```
RewriteRule . /product/index.php?prod=%1-%2 [QSA,L]
```

Also edited match as . and ^.*$ are equivalent in this case